# Drupal Views: Display most commented nodes

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I'm wondering how I can display the most commented nodes in a page. I am using Drupal 7, trying to list 10 to 20 nodes on the bases of comment count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view and set a sort by comment count and select display 'Display a specified number of items' for a pager and select your size as 10 to 20. Let me know if you need more help finding these settings.